# Video in evince in presentation mode

Tags: video, latex, evince

I have created a presentation with the LaTeX Beamer class that contains a video. If I open the pdf file (with evince) not in presentation mode everything is fine. I can start the video with a simple mouse click. But in presentation mode the pointer doesn't become active on the placeholder image and I cannot start the video.

I'm using version 3.18.2 of evince.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Bug reports are off topic here.

Comment: I have now created a bug report. I will post an answer if there is any outcome. I hoped someone knows a workaround for this problem.

Comment: The same is happening with the other attach files (eg. music)

Comment: This is also a very old bug with nothing happening to fix it for a long time now.

Comment: @Thorsten as a side note, can you post a link to the bug report you created so that we can all pitch in?

Comment: Bug report can be found under: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792193

Comment: I'm seeing this too with evince 3.30.1 on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.10. The bug has migrated to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/869.